# sample test case is running well, but when i submit, it keeps on processing(HACKERRANK) (PROBLEM NAME-Grading Students)

Tags: python, testcase

**Sam is a professor at the university and likes to round each student's
according to these rules:**

**1) If the difference between the grades and the next multiple of 5 is less than 3, round up to the next multiple of 5**

**2)If the value of grade is less than 38, no rounding occurs as the result will still be a failing grade.**

```py
def gradingStudents(grades):
    # Write your code here
    gr = [None]*len(grades)
    j = 0


    for i in grades:

        e = 5- (i% 5)
        if e < 3 and i+e >= 40 and i+e <= 100:
            gr[j] = i + e
        else:
            gr[j] = i
        j += 1


    return gr;
```

```
Sample Input 0

4
73
67
38
33

Sample Output 0

75
67
40
33
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please state what part of the program is giving you issues. Anyone who comes across your question should be able to know what problem you're having. This question leaves that up to the reader, significantly reducing the chances of it getting answered. Edit your question with what specific issue you're having with the code and we may be able to help.

Comment: thst's the issue, i don't know which part is causing problem, the submission just keeps on processing

Comment: Hi Premjeet, there seems to be issue at Hackerrank server end. I am also getting same behavior for already accepted problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a temporary backend problem at Hackerrank.

Comment: can you tell what kind of backend proble?